# Javascript error on bootbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i made a jquery validator to pass vars to .php "secretly" but when I click on the submit button it just displays an error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: bootbox is not defined

at HTMLFormElement. < anonymous > (validacao.js: 68)
at HTMLFormElement.dispatch(jquery.min.js: 3)
at HTMLFormElement.r.handle(jquery.min.js: 3)
at Object.trigger(jquery.min.js: 3)
at HTMLFormElement. < anonymous > (jquery.min.js: 3)
at Function.each(jquery.min.js: 2)
at n.fn.init.each(jquery.min.js: 2)
at n.fn.init.trigger(jquery.min.js: 3)
at BootstrapValidator._submit(bootstrapValidator.js: 527)
at BootstrapValidator.validate(bootstrapValidator.js: 813)
```

This is my validação.js line 68

```
 var dialog = bootbox.dialog({
    message: '<p class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i>Fazendo login...</p>',
    closeButton: false
 });
```

What i'm doing wrong? are there syntax errors or logic errors?

Comment: have you included the file where bootbox is defined.

Answer (score 0):

The js file that contains bootbox is not defined. Add it and try again